# "Живучий" сервис

Tags: android, service

Всем привет!
Столкнулся со следующей задачей - у меня есть сервис, который каждые 5 минут звонит. Если пользователь "усыпляет" телефон, то сервис перестает работать и продолжает работу после "пробуждения". Нужно чтобы сервис работал и подавал сигналы даже в спящем режиме телефона.
Наткнулся на класс WakefulIntentService. Есть ли другие варианты, как это еще можно сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сделать [lock](http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/02/07/android-wakelock/). Правда пользователи за это по голове не погладят, а скорее надают пинков - батарею садит очень быстро.

Comment: Это в моей программе уже есть - сервис все равно начинает дрыхнуть вместе с системой.
По поводу пользователей - он один, это мой заказчик, ему главное чтобы все работало как нужно.
Насчет батареи - в курсе.

Comment: Может все таки отпускаете лок? видите там такую строку `wakeLock.acquire(1000);` - это отпустит лок через одну секунду.

Comment: Да, я уже заметил, буду пробовать, отпишусь о результатах.